# FHIR: ProcedureRequest How to retrieve all data fields of ProcedureRequest?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am unable to retrieve all the fields, which i post for ProcedureRequest to a FHIR database.

Step 1: Post Request

```
curl -X POST https://fhir.dstu2.safetylabs.org/api/smartdstu2/open/ProcedureRequest \
        -H 'Content-type: application/json+fhir' \
        --data @ProcedureRequest.js
```

Result of POST

```
    {
    "resourceType":"OperationOutcome",
    "text":{
        "status":"generated",
        "div":"<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><h1>Operation Outcome</h1><table border=\"0\"><tr><td style=\"font-weight: bold;\">information</td><td>[]</td><td><pre>Successfully created resource &quot;ProcedureRequest/7660/_history/1&quot; in 7ms</pre></td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t</tr>\n\t\t</table>\n\t</div>"
    },
    "issue":[
        {
            "severity":"information",
            "code":"informational",
            "diagnostics":"Successfully created resource \"ProcedureRequest/7660/_history/1\" in 7ms"
        }
    ]
}
```

This request was successful.

The JSON was validated from JSON validator, and It is also validated from hapi test Server from given link

```
" https://fhirtest.uhn.ca/resource?serverId=home_21&pretty=false&resource=ProcedureRequest"
```

Step 2: Retrieve Request

```
curl -X GET https://fhir.dstu2.safetylabs.org/api/smartdstu2/open/ProcedureRequest/7660
```

Results of GET

```
    {
    "resourceType":"ProcedureRequest",
    "id":"7660",
    "meta":{
        "versionId":"1",
        "lastUpdated":"2017-11-18T13:49:23.000+00:00"
    },
    "text":{
        "status":"generated",
        "div":"<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><p><b>Generated Narrative with Details</b></p><p><b>id</b>: subrequest</p><p><b>definition</b>: Protocol for alergies</p><p><b>basedOn</b>: Original Request</p><p><b>replaces</b>: Previous allergy test</p><p><b>requisition</b>: A13848392</p><p><b>status</b>: active</p><p><b>intent</b>: instance-order</p><p><b>priority</b>: routine</p><p><b>code</b>: Peanut IgG <span>(Details : {LOINC code '35542-0' = 'Peanut IgG Ab [Mass/volume] in Serum)</span></p><p><b>subject</b>: <a>Patient/dicom</a></p><p><b>occurrence</b>: 08/05/2013 9:33:27 AM</p><h3>Requesters</h3><table><tr><td>-</td><td><b>Agent</b></td></tr><tr><td>*</td><td><a>Dr. Adam Careful</a></td></tr></table><p><b>performerType</b>: Nurse <span>(Details : {[not stated] code 'null' = 'null', given as 'Qualified nurse'})</span></p><p><b>reasonCode</b>: Check for Peanut Allergy <span>(Details )</span></p><p><b>bodySite</b>: Right arm <span>(Details : {[not stated] code 'null' = 'null', given as 'Right arm'})</span></p></div>"
    },
    "subject":{
        "reference":"Patient/SL88812358"
    },
    "code":{
        "coding":[
            {
                "system":"http://loinc.org",
                "code":"35542-0"
            }
        ],
        "text":"Peanut IgG"
    },
    "bodySite":[
        {
            "coding":[
                {
                    "display":"Right arm"
                }
            ],
            "text":"Right arm"
        }
    ],
    "status":"active",
    "priority":"routine"
}
```

Note that Retrieve did not retrieve the following fields

- occurrenceTiming
- occurrenceDateTime
- performerType
- reasonCode
- requester

Question : How do I request all the fields I posted?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you posted to a DSTU2 server and those elements don't exist in DSTU2 - so the server ignored them (as servers are allowed to do with unrecognized elements).  If you post to a DSTU3 server, the elements should be stored - if the server supports them, which most test servers do.